# Migration SVN to GIT with Bitbucket SVN Mirror

Tags: git, svn, migration

We plan to migrate our SVN repo to GIT. We host the whole thing in Bitbucket on our Servers. I have found an Bitbucket-Addon called "SVN Mirror" which supports migration and also mirroring.

While I am testing I am struggling a little bit with the structure in SVN. Actually we have a structure like this:

> Databases
>
> > Pipelines
> >
> > > trunk
> > >
> > > > Project_1
> > > >
> > > > Project_2
> > > >
> > > > Project_3
> > >
> > > Branches
> > >
> > > > Branch_1
> > > >
> > > > > Project_4
> > > > >
> > > > > Project_5
> > > >
> > > > Branch_2
> > > >
> > > > > Project_6
> > > > >
> > > > > Project_7
> >
> > Entities
> >
> > > trunk
> > >
> > > > Project_1
> > > >
> > > > Project_2
> > > >
> > > > Project_3
> > >
> > > Branches
> > >
> > > > Branch_1
> > > >
> > > > > Project_4
> > > > >
> > > > > Project_5
> > > >
> > > > Branch_2
> > > >
> > > > > Project_6
> > > > >
> > > > > Project_7

Is this kind of structure ok for migration into GIT or would there be a potential issue regarding the above SVN-Structure?

For example in the mentioned Bitbucked addon I can define an manual mapping of the branch, tags, etc.

This is what is suggested:

```
trunk = trunk:refs/heads/master
branches = branches/*:refs/heads/*
tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
shelves = shelves/*:refs/shelves/*
```

Would this suggestion be correct regarding the mentioned actual SVN structure?

Any help is very appreciated :)

Thank you in advance

Cheers
Sandro

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how you want to split the SVN repository into Git repositories. The rule of thumb: if

```
some/path/one
```

and

```
  some/path/two
```

have approximately the same content, they should be inside the same Git repository, otherwise, if they are unrelated projects, they should be split into different Git repositories.

**Case 1:** All `Databases/XXX/trunk/Project_YYY` and `Databases/XXX/Branches_ZZZ/Project_YYY` have the approximately same content.

In this case you have 1 Git repository and the configuration could be the following: SVN URL should be `http://server/some/path/Databases` (i.e. Databases can be included into the URL)

```
trunk = Pipelines/trunk/Project_1:refs/heads/pipelines/trunk/Project_1
branches = Pipelines/trunk/*:refs/heads/pipelines/trunk/*
branches = Pipelines/Branches/*/*:refs/heads/pipelines/branches/*/*
branches = Entities/trunk/*:refs/heads/entities/trunk/*
branches = Entities/Branches/*/*:refs/heads/entities/branches/*/*
```

**Case 2:** Every Project_YYY is an individual Git repository. In that case

Git repository for Project_1 will have the following configuration:

```
trunk = Pipelines/trunk/Project_1:refs/heads/pipelines/trunk/Project_1
branches = Entities/trunk/Project_1:refs/heads/entities/trunk/Project_1
```

Git repository for Project_2 will have the following configuration:

```
trunk = Pipelines/trunk/Project_2:refs/heads/pipelines/trunk/Project_2
branches = Entities/trunk/Project_2:refs/heads/entities/trunk/Project_2
```

Git repository for Project_3 will have the following configuration:

```
trunk = Pipelines/trunk/Project_3:refs/heads/pipelines/trunk/Project_3
branches = Entities/trunk/Project_3:refs/heads/entities/trunk/Project_3
```

Git repository for Project_4 will have the following configuration:

```
trunk = Pipelines/Branches/Branch_1/Project_4:refs/heads/pipelines/Branches/Branch_1/Project_4
branches = Entities/Branches/Branch_1/Project_4:refs/heads/entities/Branches/Branch_1/Project_4
```

Git repository for Project_5 will have the following configuration:

```
trunk = Pipelines/Branches/Branch_1/Project_5:refs/heads/pipelines/Branches/Branch_1/Project_5
branches = Entities/Branches/Branch_1/Project_5:refs/heads/entities/Branches/Branch_1/Project_5
```

Git repository for Project_6 will have the following configuration:

```
trunk = Pipelines/Branches/Branch_2/Project_6:refs/heads/pipelines/Branches/Branch_2/Project_6
branches = Entities/Branches/Branch_2/Project_6:refs/heads/entities/Branches/Branch_2/Project_6
```

Git repository for Project_7 will have the following configuration:

```
trunk = Pipelines/Branches/Branch_2/Project_7:refs/heads/pipelines/Branches/Branch_2/Project_7
branches = Entities/Branches/Branch_2/Project_7:refs/heads/entities/Branches/Branch_2/Project_7
```

**Case 3:** One repository for Pipelines, another one for Entities. You have 2 Git repositories, the Git repository for 
Pipelines will look like:

```
trunk = Pipelines/trunk/Project_1:refs/heads/pipelines/trunk/Project_1
branches = Pipelines/trunk/*:refs/heads/pipelines/trunk/*
branches = Pipelines/Branches/*/*:refs/heads/pipelines/branches/*/*
```

The Git repository for Entities will look like:

```
trunk = Entities/trunk/Project_1:refs/heads/entities/trunk/Project_1
branches = Entities/trunk/*:refs/heads/entities/trunk/*
branches = Entities/Branches/*/*:refs/heads/entities/branches/*/*
```

I hope you get the idea and can create the configuration based on your needs.

Comment: Hi Dmitry

Thank you so much for your awesome reply, Very detailed and informative :) *thumbs up*

I will check an give feedback regarding the outcome,

Comment: Hello Dmitry

I have one more question regarding Case 3 which would be the best fit for us.

Since I have more then 1 project, lets say in "Pipelines", do I need to add the same config for each project? So for Project_1, Project_2, etc?

Comment: Hi, I have tried with the Case 3 config, but nothing has been imported. Unfortunately its not clear to me why there are two branch configs and one is pointing to trunk. Aso the fact why to put the reference to Project_1 for example since I have quite alot Projects in the Pipelines section. Maybe you could clarify?

Maybe I set the wrong SVN-URL?

I've set this one: http://server/some/path/Databases/pipelines

Comment: Hi, to keep the format of StackOverflow, it would be better if you copy-paste and send your questions to support@subgit.com. If you start the letter with "Hi Dmitry", it will be redirected to me. When we find all the answers I'll post them here or update the answer.